# Google Play Upload Failed 'You uploaded a debuggable APK'

Tags: android, google-play

I am running into the following message when attempting to upload my APK as an alpha release on Google Play.

'**You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.**'

In my gradle I have configured the signing config and build type(s) as follows:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("PATH TO KEY STORE")
        storePassword "STORE PASSWORD"
        keyAlias "ALIAS"
        keyPassword "PASSWORD"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        testCoverageEnabled true
        debuggable false
    }
    debug { testCoverageEnabled true }
}
```

Furthermore, I've verified using jarsigner that my APK was signed and that the CN does **not** contain `CN=Android Debug`.

The manifest for the APK does **not** contain the attribute `android:debuggable`.

The application I've built is a Kotlin application with the following dependencies:

> Android Support v13 27.0.2
>
> Android Support Annotations 27.0.2
>
> Android Support Constraint Layout 1.0.2
>
> Junit 4.12
>
> Mockito 2.15.0
>
> Robolectric 3.7
>
> Android Support Test Runner 1.0.1
>
> Android Support Test Espresso Core 3.0.1

I've attempted to upload the APK generated via gradle command line (i.e., **gradle build**) as well as the APK generated from the IDE using *Build, Generate
Signed APK*, and I've ensured that the **release** variant is selected when building from the IDE and gradle before attempting to upload to Google Play.

Finally, I've attempted this with multiple keystores (creating a new one thinking that perhaps my first one was invalid), and still I cannot upload my APK.  To clarify, **this is the first apk upload**.  No prior version exists on Google Play.

Is one of the support libraries leading to this issue, or is there something I have missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered the issue.

It seems an APK with **test coverage enabled** is considered **debuggable**.

After removing the line

```
testCoverageEnabled true
```

from my release build type, I was able to upload my APK.